# Capybara, selecting checkbox type label, no checkbox shown

Tags: ruby, checkbox, cucumber, capybara

The code looks something like this:

```
    <span ng-switch-when="boolGroup" class="ng-scope">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">
                                   Available tabs:
                            </label>
    <span ng-repeat="key in detail.keys" class="something ng-scope">
    <input type="checkbox" id="TAB_1" style="display: none;" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
    <label ng_class="something something..." for="TAB_1" class="ng-binding auth-selected-editable">
        Example
</label>
    </span> ... </span>
```

And I need to select label: "Example", it is checkbox type but no checkbox is shown. So basically it is shown like select box, but in html code it is checkbox.

Capybara says :  `Unable to find checkbox "Tab_1" <Capybara::ElementNotFound>`

Comment: you can select tab like this, `find(:xpath, '//*[contains(@id, "Tab_1")]')`, add `click()` after find(*), if want to change checkbox value.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot.